# Writing SMTP Client in Java without Java Mail API or any third party API

Tags: java, authentication, smtp, gmail

I am asking this and I am terribly embarrassed. I am implementing an SMTP client without using Java MAIL API or any other third party encryption library, open source or not as I am not fond of third party APIs and wish to do stuff my way on my terms. I know it is arrogant but it is the way I am. So, far I have this: -

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Base64;

public class SocketSample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Socket socket = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        String uid = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("xyz@gmail.com".getBytes());
        String pwd = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("abc123".getBytes());
        System.out.println(uid);
        System.out.println(pwd);
        //char ans = '\0';
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter host: ");
        String host = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter port: ");
        int port = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
        if (socket.isConnected())
        {

            System.out.println("Socket connected.");
            out = socket.getOutputStream();
            String command = "HELO " + host + "\r\n";
            byte[] data = command.getBytes();
            out.write(data);
            out.flush();
            //
            in = socket.getInputStream();
            int c = '\0';
            while (c != -1)
            {
                c = in.read();
                System.out.print((char) c);
            }
            //
            command = "STARTTLS\r\n";
            data = command.getBytes();
            out.write(data);
            out.flush();
            c = '\0';
            while(c != -1)
            {
                c = in.read();
                System.out.print((char) c);
            }
            /*
            command = "HELO " + host + "\r\n";
            data = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(command.getBytes()).getBytes();
            out.write(data);
            out.flush();
            c = '\0';
            while(c != -1)
            {
                c = in.read();
                System.out.print((char) c);
            }
            */
            System.out.println(uid);
            System.out.println(pwd);
            command = "AUTH PLAIN " + uid + "\r\n";
            data = command.getBytes();
            out.write(data);
            out.flush();
            c = '\0';
            while(c != -1)
            {
                c = in.read();
                System.out.print((char) c);
            }
            //
            command = pwd + "\r\n";
            data = command.getBytes();
            out.write(data);
            out.flush();
            c = '\0';
            while (c != -1)
            {
                c = in.read();
                System.out.print((char) c);
            }
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        socket.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This gets stuck at STARTTLS and although I am encoding with base64 the user-name and pass-word but it remains stuck there. What wrong am I doing? Please, help me out.
Thank you!
P. S.: - I am new to Java.

Comment: I'm not sure I should be encouraging you but `in.read()` isn't going to return -1 until the other side has closed down. If you're going to do this with even a rudimentary success, I suggest you be 100% sure of the raw protocol. The signs are that you're not…

Comment: Thank you very much sir. And yes my knowledge of the protocol is rudimentary to say the least. I'm reading it's specs and with other reads I'm sure the process is correct but the mistake some where is in implementation like choosing correct reader and writer, using commands in correct format etc. Can you give me a few more hints, sir? Thank you.

Comment: My recommendation is that you annotate your code with the specifics of what the server is going to send and what you as client as going to send

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. I have achieved what I was willing to. Good luck to you for future, sir. Thank you very much once again!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to rely on the `inputStream::available()` method for reading the content. In that way, you may create a helper method like

```
private static String readResponse(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    int c;
    StringBuilder raw = new StringBuilder();
    do {
        c = inputStream.read();
        raw.append((char) c);
    } while (inputStream.available() > 0);
    return raw.toString();
}
```

Then replace code block

```
int c = '\0';
while (c != -1) {
    c = in.read();
    System.out.print((char) c);
}
```

on the `System.out.println(readResponse(in));`.

In that way you would proceed to the **STARTTLS** command, but I'm not sure you should send it because own implementation of TLS using plain Sockets is not something you would like to do as a home task.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I'll follow your recommendations forthwith. Wish me luck.

Comment: On the SO if you got an answer, you could mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Well sir Mr. Eugene, like you said, I was able to send STARTTLS but then host reset the connection and program raised SocketException. Any idea why, sir?

Comment: After the *STARTTLS* command you should start a real TLS session, but you are still trying to send something in a plain text, which will not work. Please, check this order of commands here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunistic_TLS

Comment: Ah! Secure communication over SSL so secure socket will work not a regular one.

Comment: At last! Mr. Eugene, sir. By the Grace of the Lord Almighty, I did it. I have successfully sent the test e-mail with my programme. Thank you very much, sir. Your help was what got me off the hook. Thank you once again. How do I close this thread, sir?

Comment: I never posted questions on SO ‍♂️  Somewhere should be a button for accepting an answer. If you not find it, then not a big deal. Good luck with programming!

Comment: Wow! That means you are a real maestro! Good luck for future, sir!

Comment: I don't want to pour cold water on this but it's worth noting that `InputStream::available()` might not *always* be reliable. It's safer to read to the beginning of blocking, at which point you should have received the response that the protocol indicates